# UISearchBar disappears after selecting row in search results TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Does anyone know why my UISearchbar is disappearing after a user taps on a cell in the search results table? What happens is a user taps a cell after searching for something, which then opens a new view. However, when you return back to the original search view controller, the search bar is gone and the top cell is under the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I had to dismiss the search results tableview after a cell was pressed. Therefore, when the user returned back to the previous view, the search results were dismissed and the original tableview appeared again.